# How to unambiguously indicate inflections where letters are sometimes removed?

Tags: grammar, morphology, inflectional-morphology, inflections

Consider a lexicon where you look up the words 'jump' and 'dance'. You would often see something like this:

- jump -s -ing, etc.
- dance -s -ing, etc.

I reckon this notation (is there a name for it?) is somewhat standardised. Most people will easily see that the *present participles* are 'jumping' and 'dancing'. But wait! Here's an ambiguity. The '-ing' suffix does not tell the reader that the trailing 'e' of the *lemma* — i.e. 'dance' — should be removed. This will confuse some readers. Hence my question.

**Is there a common way to indicate a removal rule, allowing for an unambiguous annotation?**

Since the lexicon should be computer readable, a simple syntax (e.g. 'ASCII') is desirable. I can think of some custom pattern like '^?-ing' (using [Caret notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_notation) for 'Backspace'), but there ought to be a standard way to describe this.

Comment: Where are you seeing this kind of notation? A quick look around the dictionaries shows no such thing.

Comment: Maybe they moved away from this some decades ago :P. Though, I have seen it in some Swedish dictionaries.

Comment: just make the root “danc” and add the -e to the list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dictionaries probably spell out the cases that cannot fit the "-" type.

jump -s -ing -ed -ed
[Or, in regular cases like this, may leave them out completely]
run -s -ning ran run
drink -s -ing drank drunk
be am is are -ing was were been

Actually, modern on-line dictionaries, not pressed for space, may spell them all out.
jump jumps jumping jumped jumped

Comment: Makes sense. I guess another possibility is to combine `-ing` with a *rule* that handles edge cases like *silent e* and *double consonants*.

Comment: There are common rules that most people are taught either as children or as ESL students: doubling single letters in stressed syllables after short vowels, dropping "e", etc.  So dictionaries may or may not assume people know these, and only indicate variations. But all these rules have exceptions, so they're not entirely reliable.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a necessary function of dictionaries to provide an exhaustive list of the inflections of verbs or nouns.  The bigger and more comprehensive the dictionary, the more likely it is that this kind of detail might be included. The definition of dictionary in the Cambridge English Dictionary on line makes this clear.

> a book that contains a list of words in alphabetical order and explains their meanings, or gives a word for them in another language; an electronic product giving similar information on a computer, smartphone, etc.:

There is no commitment here to go into their morphology.

There are however other ways in which some dictionaries, including the Cambridge English Dictionary, can and do provide the information you seek.  Most larger dictionaries provide examples of the standard uses of a word.  Among the examples for *dance* provided by CEG, for example, is "dancing".  [https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dance]

Similarly for the verb '*slip*' it provides examples of the past tense, where the final 'p' is doubled.  The participle use is not exemplified, but an attentive searcher ought to be able to realise if the past has a doubled 'p', so must the present participle.